# Steam on wine says that I have incompatible OS version

Tags: wine, games, steam

I'm trying to play Hitman Absolution via wine on Ubuntu. I've installed steam in wine and downloaded the game but Steam says:

```
Your OS version in unsupported. This product requires Windows Vista SP2 or newer.
```

In wine configuration I've chosen to emulate Windows 8 by default (also tried windows 7)

So am I doing something wrong?

What can I do about it?

Comment: I've  never heard of that. Your wine prefixes are probably not up to date, but that's just a guess.

Comment: Well, that's not very helpful. I have a pretty fresh wine installation 1.7 something. And I have 64 bit wineprefix (whatever that means). Can you say, what should I do?

Comment: It looks like your prefixes are updated. Do you have "PlayOnLinux" ?

Comment: I've removed it earlier.

Comment: Well, I don't really know what's wrong with Steam on wine. The best guess I would give you is to install PlayOnLinux, and install steam from there.

Comment: Just tried it. Doesn't work.

Comment: What Duck said.. It's probably not supported

Answer (score 0):

Not all games will work running Wine. Unfortunately, yours seems to be one of the ones that doesn't seem to work very well:

https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=14704

Comment: Yeah, well there isn't anything there which fit my description AFAIK. So it might actually work in my case. So it's not an answer, sorry.